# Worst tournament performances of reigning World Champions

Tags: tournament, world-championship, carlsen

As a Magnus Carlsen fan, it was a bit disappointing for me to see him finish clear second in Biel 2018, one and half points after Mamedyarov, after starting the tournament with two wins - and it could have been two points - had not the much lower-rated Georgiadis blundered in a drawn endgame. Although not a bad performance *per se*, I was wondering what were the worst tournament performances of reigning World Champions?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Looking through this list of strong [tournaments](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_strong_chess_tournaments), among those that stand out are:

- [AVRO 1938](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AVRO_1938_chess_tournament), where Alekhine finished 6/8.
- [Tillburg, 1996](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tilburg_chess_tournament#1996), where Karpov finished 6/12.
- [1st Grand Slam Masters Final (2008)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bilbao_Chess_Masters_Final), where Anand finished in last (6th) place.

Comment: The Grand Slam Masters Final may just be the worst one overall. I still remember all the "hiding prep" jokes.

Answer (score 7):

For Carlsen that was probably [Norway Chess 2017](http://www.chessgames.com/perl/chess.pl?tid=90303), where he finished second to last on -1.

Comment: I'd say Norway Chess 2015 was even worse for Carlsen: 3.5/9 (although he finished shared 7th) and losing against Hammer, one of his seconds. Can I edit your answer or should I post it as a new answer?

Comment: I will take Anand's Bilbao 2008 as the worst performance, since he was clear last and at -2.

Comment: He wasn't world champion at that point, though.